# R Reticulate change conda path

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have two Anaconda packages installed, one with Python 2 and one with Python 3. When I installed Reticulate in R and tried to call `reticulate::source_python`, it gives an error

`Error: Specified conda binary 'C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/CONTIN~1/ANACON~2/Scripts/conda.exe' does not exist.`

So I'd like to change the default `specified conda binary` path to Anaconda3. How can I do that?

I tried to call `reticulate::conda_binary("C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe")` before anything and it ran fine. But it doesn't seem to take effect when I later ran the `source_python` call.